# App Center Install Id is returning null for push notification?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using App Center for Push Notification in xamarin forms.

I have followed all the steps required for App Center as well as Firebase.

But still i am getting null value for install id

```
var guid = AppCenter.GetInstallIdAsync().Result
```

Need your help to debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallId on Xamarin Android is null if called before the start method of the SDK.

Dont forget to update Appcenter Nuget packages, there was a specific old version with a bug on the `GetInstallIdAsync` method

Another thing: dont use .Result. Await the method in your `Onstart` method like this:

```cs
    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        AppCenter.Start("ios=-----;android=----", typeof(Push));
        var guid = await AppCenter.GetInstallIdAsync();
    }
```

Since OnStart is just an event, and nothing is waiting for it’s return, using async void is acceptable here.

I'm doing this in my apps and it works

Comment: I also figured it shortly after putting this question but still thanks for your response.

Comment: but i am not able to achieve Push To User notification do you have any idea about it?

Comment: eh, sometimes i found myself with the same problem with Push to User. Even when i pass the instance id correctly sometimes the push doesnt work. Sometimes i have just to wait a couple of minutes. Maybe its better to ask more informations in the AppCenter Github page

Comment: No Problem, Thanks